# ggplot2::geom_segment. How to set multiple sizes, say c(10,12)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting with ggplot a data frame of different actions (A,B) not mutually exclusive and have multiple Ids.
The activities often overlap within an Id, which might cause that some are not visible.

The data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2"), x1 = c(10, 9, 12, 12 ), x2 = c(16, 17, 15, 19), type = c("A", "B", "A", "B"))
```

The codes

```
library("ggplot2")
```

This works:

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = df, aes(colour = type, x = x1, xend = x2, y = id, yend = id), size = 10)
```

Result: overlapping B and A. How to specify different `geom`_segment `size`?

Does not work:

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = df, aes(colour = type, x = x1, xend = x2, y = id, yend = id), size = c(10,12,10,12))
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2):
>   size

Comment: what is si in `size = si`?

Comment: the size. Sorry. Updated to size = 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your sizes map to activity types. In that case you can just put `size=type` in the aesthetic mapping like any other part of your graph, and then specify how the different sizes will work using `scale_size_discrete`:

```
# Put all data and aesthetics that apply to the whole plot in the original
#   ggplot() call
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, aes(colour = type, x = x1, xend = x2, y = id, yend = id, size=type)) +
    geom_segment() +
    # A is drawn first so make it bigger
    scale_size_discrete(range=c(12, 8))
```

Result:

[image: Plot with sizes mapped to activity types]

Comment: seems like using size = type give the following warning: Warning message:
Using size for a discrete variable is not advised. This is common in the ggplot guide http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guides.html What's the reason for this?

Comment: Mapping size to discrete classes in something like a scatterplot is probably not a good idea, as you can't easily distinguish the separate classes by size. That doesn't apply for your plot though. It's just a warning of a potential problem, you can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = df[df$type=="A", ], aes(colour = type, x = x1, xend = x2, y = id, yend = id), size = 12)+
  geom_segment(data = df[df$type=="B", ], aes(colour = type, x = x1, xend = x2, y = id, yend = id), size = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: it works well. however, the main issue with this approach is that the codes are part of a function and the number of types (A,B,C, etc.) is unknown or large. Hence, it would require a loop.

Comment: You are right. It is an ugly answer. I just thought about writing a different approach. I believe other answers such @Marius's answer is far more better than mine.

Comment: it's a nice answer for small number of 'types', and you didn't know the data.frame might have more then 2.

Comment: I see that this question is quite old but it's being useful to me now. How did you get the same size of the boxes in the legend when you have two different sizes in the segments? I tried now and I get two different sizes in the legend (as in the post above)

Answer (score 2):

I think the placement of a ')' before size is what the issue was. It should be part of aes.

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
geom_segment(data = df, aes(colour = type, x = x1, xend = x2, y = id, 
yend = id, size = c(10,12,10,12)))
```

@aelwan raised a valid point. I have an edit using the position parameter.

```
 ggplot(df) +
 geom_segment(aes(x = x1, xend = x2,
 y = id, yend = id, colour = type),size =10, position = position_dodge(width = 
 .5))
```

Comment: Your answer gave me this plot, A is not visible to me 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwnlyo2o2lgef84/Rplot01.png?dl=0